# importing jar file into jsp not working

Tags: jsp, servlets, jar

There're lotta questions out there already, but nothing seems to solve this issue. I have a 3rd party jar file placed in `WEB-INF\lib` folder. The main class `Control` exists in a folder named `Mainn`. If invoking the main method of the main class should run the jar file, whats the problem with the following code?

```
   <%@ page import="Mainn.Control"%>
   <% String[] a=new String[1];
   Mainn.Control.main(a); %>
```

Or is there any other way to make this jar file run from the jsp page?
Edit : All I'm getting is a blank screen. No error.

Comment: Tell us: what's the problem?

Comment: Look at the edit.. Im gettin a blank screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order not to have a blank screen, you would have to write something to the output writer of the JSP. But you don't do it. All you do is call a method of a class. This class, I guess, has `System.out.println()` statements. But `System.out.println()` writes to the console of your JSP container (tomcat or whatever you're using), on the server. It doesn't write to the JSP's writer.

Comment: Whoa. . So running the jar from jsp does not mean that the jar would pop up as if we open it? We have to handle everythin in jsp instead eh?

Comment: JSPs are executed at server-side. If it "pops up" (and I assume you mean that a frame is shown by this), it will pop up on the server, not on the client.

Comment: Guess I gotta buckle down. Thanks for that